# How to use S3 adapter cli for snowball

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm using s3 adapter to copy files from a snowball device to local machine.

Everything appears to be in order as I was able to run this command and see the bucket name:

```
aws s3 ls --endpoint http://snowballip:8080
```

But besides this, aws doesn't offer any examples for calling cp command. How do I provide the bucket name and the key with this --endpoint flag.

Further, when I ran this:

```
 aws s3 ls --endpoint http://snowballip:8080/bucketname
```

It returned 'Bucket'... Not sure what that means because I expect to see the files.

Comment: Speculation: `aws s3 ls --endpoint http://snowballip:8080 s3://bucketname`?

Comment: I don't directly know, but I agree with @sqlbot -- Just add the `--endpoint ...` parameter to the command you would normally run. It is simply sending the request to a different endpoint, but the commands operate as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the following is correct for snowball and snowball edge, as @sqlbot says in the comment

```
aws s3 ls --endpoint http://snowballip:8080 s3://bucketname/[optionalprefix]
```

References:

- [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/#options)
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/snowball/latest/ug/using-adapter-cli.html
- Just got one in the post